# Contact photo not displaying in Messages app

Tags: messages, iphone, ios

How can I display the contact photo in my Messages app?  My device is running iOS 10.3.3.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) It'd be good if you could [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/301994/edit) your question to provide further info. For example, do you also have other Apple devices that also share your Contacts via iCloud? Also, is this problem only happening with one contact, or all contacts? Finally, it'd be good to know what you've already tried so you don't get answers suggesting the same things .

Answer (score 1):

[4"-screen iOS devices (including your 5, as well as the 5S, C, and SE) no longer have the option to display contact photos.](https://www.howtoisolve.com/message-is-not-showing-contact-picture-iphone/)

If you decide to upgrade to a larger phone, check to make sure that zoom is turned off and show contact photos is turned on.

[image]